# Simple Digital Safe, Knowing what order a user presses buttons

Tags: c#, button, combinations

I have three buttons (button1, button2, button3), displaying respectively 1, 2 and 3 on them

Now what I want to do is having a secret combination to 'unlock' the program, i.e. '13221'

But I have no clue on how I can know if a user has pressed a button, and how I can check the order?

My current logic is:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(button1.KeyPress=true && button3.KeyPress=true && button2.KeyPress=true && button2.KeyPress=true && button1.KeyPress=true)
  {
    label1.Visible = true;
    label2.Visible = true;
  }
}
```

Which doesn't work obviously.. 
Anyone can help me out? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a StringBuilder object to store each keyed value into.  So in each button's click event, you will Append the '1', '2', or '3' depending on which button is pressed, and then check the current sequence.

```
StringBuilder _code = new StringBuilder();

void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _code.Append('1');

  CheckCode();
}

// ... similarly implement other button click events


void CheckCode()
{
    if (_code.ToString().Contains("13221"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ACCESS GRANTED");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did as you said but it's still not working :/
No errors though

Comment: Did you implement the click events for the other 2 buttons? (...button2_Click, button3_Click)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply register each incoming button press. For a normal button, use the ButtnClick event.

Store the value in a list. That could be a simple string.  Check each time if the list is equal to your secret code.

I think you still need specs for how and when to reset an attempt.

You are in effect making a state-machine.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest thing that jumps out at me is that you need to use `==` in your if statement to check equality.  a single `=` is assigning those properties to true.

That being said, the approach I would take for this is:

-Give each button a unique id

-On each button click, store the id in a list.

-Either after each click, or when the user presses a submit button, check the list against your predefined combination.

Answer (score 1):

The object sender button can be typed into a button where you can check the name of the button allowing you to use your single if statement.

```
Button buttonPressed = (button)Sender;
```

There should be information on MSDN on it getting doing the type conversion from object to button. (I'm at work or I would make sure my code is 100% copy paste worthy, if someone who has done this wants to edit my post feel free.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should correct your code as said by **Ian**

correct it to

```
if(button1.KeyPress==true....
```

or

```
if(button1.KeyPress.Equals(true)...  //recommended in C#
```

Then
1) Set `keypreview --> true` in form property.
2) Implement the button functions on `form_keypress` event. 
3) Take a textbox and set the properties to make it transparent
4) Implement `text_changed` event function to textbox to check the combination.

This may not work but i hope this concept has given you some idea.